# WPF maximized Window getting bigger than my screen

Tags: c#, wpf

When creating a WPF window with `AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"` and maximizing it via

```
private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState != WindowState.Maximized)
                Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            else
            
                Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
```

the Window gets bigger than my screen.

When I set `ResizeMode` to `ResizeMode="NoResize"` it works like a charm.
But I want to resize my window. Any suggestions how to fix my problem?

Comment: Show your XAML.

Comment: `WindowStyle="None"` <-- Why are you using this?

Comment: Do you have any scale settings set in windows under Display settings -> Scale and layout or is the scale set to 100% ?

Comment: It is a known issue. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=WM_GETMINMAXINFO+maximized

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MaxHeight property of that window to
SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight in the constructor. This might not work on extended desktop.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using SystemParameters like this.

```
private void btnMaximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    this.Height = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
    }
```